# Find value via property name in json.net?

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I have this simple json response  :

```
   {
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "277",
                    "short_name": "277",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "United States",
                    "short_name": "US",
                    "types": [
                        "country",
                        "political"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "long_name": "11211",
                    "short_name": "11211",
                    "types": [
                        "postal_code"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "277 Bedford Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA"
        },
        {
            "a": 2
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

How can I get the green value according to (yellow) `types` which contains `"country"` ?

visualization :

[image]

Is it possible to do it via json Linq ? `(Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObjec)`

*Something like this **psuedo** :  ( doesn't work/compile)*

```
 JObject jt=   JObject.Parse(dataObjects);
 jt["results"].Where(f=>f.key=="address_components").Where(g=>g["types"].contains("country")).select(h=>h["long_name")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

```
jt["results"].Children()
    .Select(t => t["address_components"])
    .Where(a => a != null)
    .Children()
    .Where(c => c["types"].Children().Contains("country"))
    .Select(a => a["long_name"])
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Is it ok to say i love you ? :-) I've been dealing with this crappy documentation for 3 hours.

Comment: I even went to direction with  dynamic and loops.....http://i.stack.imgur.com/fUKXy.jpg

Comment: f we're here , if I have "United states", how can I get the property name which holds it ? ("long_name" here) - I have done this - but it seems ugly : http://i.stack.imgur.com/LOWlW.jpg

Comment: I think this is the best way to get it. Another possibility is to use dynamics. You can cast a dynamic object to a `Dictionary<string, object>` and then you can handle that dictionary. But your solution would be better.